# Retrieving Field Value from Form Input Generated Dynamatically

Tags: javascript, yui

I am not sure whether this only happens to me. Basically if I have a new element added to the page using YUI

```
var element = new YAHOO.util.Element(document.createElement('input'));
element.set('value', 'some value');
element.appendTo(document.body);
```

Then I read the value of the element using these different ways, and get consistent result

```
element.get('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').getAttribute('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').value; // get 'some value'
// jquery as reference
jQuery(element.get('element').val()); // get 'some value'
```

If I change the field value through the browser (for example, 'new value'), and repeat the above steps again, i get some interesting values

```
element.get('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').getAttribute('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').value; // get 'new value'
// jquery as reference
jQuery(element.get('element').val()); // get 'new value'
```

However, if the input element is already exists in the page and is currently holding user input -> 'some value'

```
var element2 = new YAHOO.util.Element('some_input');
```

First read get same result as above scenario

```
element.get('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').getAttribute('value'); // get 'some value'
element.get('element').value; // get 'some value'
// jquery as reference
jQuery(element.get('element').val()); // get 'some value'
```

if the user enters 'new value' to the input field through the browser, then repeating the above steps gets

```
element.get('value'); // get 'new value'
element.get('element').getAttribute('value'); // get 'new value'
element.get('element').value; // get 'new value'
// jquery as reference
jQuery(element.get('element').val()); // get 'new value'
```

I am just wondering why would I get different values for dynamically generated element if different way of retrieving data is used, or it is just because I am doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old values popping up might be a caching issue.

I built your example using the latest YUI libraries here: http://tivac.com/yui2/jeffrey04_element.htm (you'll want to have Firebug open).

Using the correct

```
element.get('value');
```

calls is returning the proper value for me in both cases.

---

Not sure why

```
element.get('element').getAttribute('value')
```

is returning null sometimes though.

If you can narrow down the cases where it's returning an incorrect value I would create a simple test case and [submit a bug](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yui2/newticket). They really appreciate feedback like that and are generally fast to respond and fix issues.

Comment: thanks, I am still using YUI2.6 so not sure if some of the issue fixed in the latest release. I do get null while calling DOM's getAttribute method as well. My test run result


element.get('value'): "some value"
element.get('element').getAttribute('value'): null
element.get('element').value: "some value"
element2.get('value'): "new value"
element2.get('element').getAttribute('value'): "some value"
element2.get('element').value: "new value"